# Is there a way to convert .doc file to HTML in Mammothjs?

Tags: reactjs, mammoth

I'm using Mammothjs to convert docx file to html in ReactJs and it works perfectly. However, it's currently not supporting doc files. Is there any way or any alternative to convert doc files to HTML? TIA

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mammoth = require("mammoth");


mammoth.convertToHtml({path: "document.docx"})
    .then(function(result){

        var html = result.value; // The generated HTML
        var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion

        console.log(html);
    })
    .done();
```

In the above code, you simply replace "document.docx" with the path of your .doc file, and Mammoth.js will generate the HTML for you. You can then use this HTML as needed in your web application.